# Styling Form Stepper

Tags: reactjs, forms, user-interface, material-ui, stepper

[![i want it to look like it][1]][1]can you please guide me that how can i customise this material UI stepper ? I mean like 1,2,3 i want to replace it with my own content and and also change the shape of each step, stepper like in this code that i copied from material Ui the stepheader/title are in rounded shapes and blue color, can you please guide me how can i change it? I am still learning and trying to customise my own stepper with shapes and stuff.

`````
import {
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  StepIcon,
  Button,
  Typography,
  Box
} from "@mui/material";

const StepIconWrapper = styled("div")({
  width: "36px",
  height: "36px",
  borderRadius: "50%",
  background: "#f4461f",
  color: "white",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
});

 const CustomStepper = styled(Stepper)(({ theme }) => ({
    "& .MuiStepConnector-lineHorizontal": {
      borderTopWidth: 3,
      borderTopColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      borderRadius: 1,
    },
    "& .MuiStepConnector-active": {
      "& .MuiStepConnector-lineHorizontal": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },
    "& .MuiStepLabel-root": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: "1rem",
    },
    "& .MuiStepLabel-active": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      fontWeight: 700,
    },
    "& .MuiStepIcon-root.MuiStepIcon-active": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  }));
<CustomStepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={index}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </CustomStepper>````

i want to change the step design , for example i am getting this stepper with 1 , 2 ,3 i want to replace it with own each form content heading and the headers are in rounded shapes, i want to customise it by converting it into other shapes.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VjSI.png
`````